# Directional derivative as scalar product

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function. The derivative of $f$ in direction $v$ is defined as

$$\nabla_v f(x)= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}$$

One can write $\nabla_v f(x) = \langle\nabla f(x),v\rangle$ since $$0=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)-\langle\nabla f(x),tv\rangle}{t\|v\|_2}=\nabla_v f(x)-\langle\nabla f(x),v\rangle.$$

Unfortunately I do not understand the explanation. Why is it $0$? Why do we suddently have $\|v\|$? Why does the equality hold?

May someone please explain this computation to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a given function. We say that $f$ is differentiable at $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ if there exists a linear transformation $T_{x}: \mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-T_{x}h}{||h||} = 0$$
holds. The linear transformation $T_{x}$ is called derivative of $f$ at $x$ and it is commonly denoted by $f'(x)$.

Every linear operator defined from a finite-dimensional vector space to another finite-dimensional vector space has a matrix representation. In this case, the matrix representation of the derivative $f'(x)$ is the so-called Jacobian matrix:
$$Jf(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{2}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{m}} \\
\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x_{2}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x_{m}}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_{n}}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial f_{n}}{\partial x_{2}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_{n}}{\partial x_{m}} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where, for each $i=1,2,...,n$, $f_{i}$ is the $i$-th entry of the function $f$, that is, $f = (f_{1},...,f_{n})$. To evaluate $f'(x)$ at $h$ is to take the matrix product of $Jf(x)$ with the column vector $h$, i.e. $f'(x)h = Jf(x)h$.

Lets get back to your question. We have $n=1$ and $m=n$, so the Jacobian matrix $Jf(x)$ has precisely one row and $n$ columns:
$$Jf(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If we define the gradient as the *vector* $\nabla f(x) = \bigg{(}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}},..., \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}}\bigg{)}$, then we see that:
$$f'(x)h = Jf(x)h = \langle \nabla f(x), h\rangle $$
Thus, in your case, a function is differentiable at $x$ if:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), h\rangle}{||h||} = 0$$
holds. In this case, the directional derivative is obtained by taking $h = tv$ for some fixed $v$ and the limit $t\to 0$, as posted by the OP.

Comment: Hello, thank you soo much for your detailed answer

Comment: @samabu you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The equality is a consequence of the differentiability of $f$ at the point $x$. Recall that $f$ is differentiable at the point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ if
$$\lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x),h \rangle}{\|h\|}=0,$$
where $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a small vector.